# Performance of MERGE statements in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was wondering how BigQuery executed [MERGE Statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement), and how it's performance compared to simply over-writing an entire table?

For example, if I have a large file with only a few rows updated/deleted/added, would it make more sense to fill a temporary table with the updated data and merge it with the old table? Or would it make to simply overwrite the entire table?

Thank you!

Comment: If you overwrite your table you loose pricing benefits for old partitions which costs less.

Comment: I think it depends on your data and write frequency. If you are able to isolate partitions involved MERGE is pretty cheap and quite fast. But you can also overwrite recent partitions which is the same. If you nedd to lookupt the entire table, you will pay for all the rows of the table. You can pay almost nothing with a load job. I think both are not that expensive but managing MERGE and a temporary table involves more operations and so more potential failure points (write the first table, merge, delete it) vs writing directly the table

Answer (score 0):

Merging can be much more efficient than just overwriting the target table, but to get the maximum gain in performance and cost, you need to follow some basic recommendations:

Partition Pruning: This strategy involves minimizing the scan on the target (and source) table by limiting the number of partitions scanned. Here's an example SQL code:

```
BEGIN
  -- First, find relevant dates (assuming you have date partition) in the source table.
  DECLARE date_list ARRAY<DATE>;
  SET date_list = (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT partition_dates_colum)
    FROM source_table
    -- Add extra conditions here.
  );

  -- Now execute your merge statement with this list to limit partition scan over the target table.
  MERGE target_table T
  USING source_table S
  ON T.key = S.key AND T.launch_date IN UNNEST(date_list)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET T.value = S.value
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (key, value, launch_date) VALUES (S.key, S.value, S.launch_date);
END;
```

2. The second strategy is clustering the target table with the column that you have in the “ON” condition of your merge is the second strategy. This strategy can improve performance and limit the scan, saving a lot of time and money.

I hope this answer helps you.